# Slider Crashes program on Iphone, but worked on simulator

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, uislider

I am using this code to track and update slider value, then convert to string and show on label. The issue is that, This code works on the simulator, but crashed on the actual phone. With error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". I can't figure out what could cause this, any help would be appreciated.

func updateSlider () {

```
    sliderBar.value = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(self.audioPlayer.currentItem!.currentTime()))
    let currentTime = Int((CMTimeGetSeconds(self.audioPlayer.currentItem!.currentTime())))
    let duration = Int((CMTimeGetSeconds(self.audioPlayer.currentItem!.asset.duration)))
    //let total = currentTime - duration

    let minutes = currentTime/60
    let seconds = currentTime - minutes * 60

    let minutes2 = duration/60
    let seconds2 = duration - minutes2 * 60

    self.lblPastTime.text = NSString(format: " %02d:%02d / %02d:%02d  ",minutes2,seconds2, minutes,seconds) as String
```

}

Comment: It looks like the only possible Optional in that code is `self.lblPastTime`. I would suggest it is probably nil.

Comment: @Michael if so wouldn't it crash on the simulator as well?

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding force unwrapping variables is a good way to avoid errors like that:

```
func updateSlider () {

    guard let currentItem = self.audioPlayer.currentItem else { return }
    sliderBar.value = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(currentItem.currentTime()))
    let currentTime = Int((CMTimeGetSeconds(currentItem.currentTime())))
    let duration = Int((CMTimeGetSeconds(currentItem.asset.duration)))
    //let total = currentTime - duration

    let minutes = currentTime/60
    let seconds = currentTime - minutes * 60

    let minutes2 = duration/60
    let seconds2 = duration - minutes2 * 60

    self.lblPastTime.text = NSString(format: " %02d:%02d / %02d:%02d  ",minutes2,seconds2, minutes,seconds) as? String

}
```

Using `guard let` I safely unwrap the variable, so if it's `nil`, the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER**

Had to use audioPlayer.currentTime()

Instead of audioPlayer.currentItem!.currentTime()

func updateSlider () {

```
    sliderBar.value = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(audioPlayer.currentTime()))
```

//        sliderBar.value = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(self.audioPlayer.currentItem!.currentTime()))

```
    let currentTime = Int((CMTimeGetSeconds(self.audioPlayer.currentItem!.currentTime())))
    let duration = Int((CMTimeGetSeconds(self.audioPlayer.currentItem!.asset.duration)))
    //let total = currentTime - duration

    let minutes = currentTime/60
    let seconds = currentTime - minutes * 60

    let minutes2 = duration/60
    let seconds2 = duration - minutes2 * 60

    self.lblPastTime.text = NSString(format: " %02d:%02d / %02d:%02d ",minutes2,seconds2, minutes,seconds) as String
```

}